# C# Drag and Drop labels within FlowLayoutPanels

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I have small problem. I want make program where I can drag generated labels between multiple FlowLayoutPanels. But last few days I have tried to make drag and drop working. I tried many tutorials, examples etc. but it is always something bit diferent and I am not able extract only basic code.

It is similar to [this program](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3ddb8d3-cea6-41d9-9276-94ddba49dc5d/drag-and-drop-groupbox-panels) but it is in Visual Basic and I need it in C#. I know it is maybe very simple, but I am newbie.

Thank you for help.

Comment: It is not a small problem.  Don't drag controls, make it look like you [drag text instead](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/36028246-7fc8-4cda-a582-de8a675a0827/drag-text-as-image?forum=winforms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real `Drag&Drop` ist most useful between applications and maybe also between `Forms`.

Assuming you want to drag `Labels` between `FLPs` on the same `Form`, the code below should get you going..

It takes two `FlowLayoutPanels` called `FLP1` and `FLP2` and starts by initializing them with a few `Labels`.

Note the three **mouse events** I add to each `Label` to emulate a `Drag&Drop` action!

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create a few Label with varying Colors for testing..
    fillFLP(FLP1, 88);
    fillFLP(FLP2, 111);
}

void fillFLP(FlowLayoutPanel FLP, int cc)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        // the next 3 lines optional and only are there for testing!
        l.AutoSize = false;      
        l.Text = FLP.Name + " " +  i.ToString("00");
        l.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, cc * 2 - i, 255 - 5 * i, cc + 5 * i); 
        // add controls and set mouse events:
        FLP.Controls.Add(l);
        l.MouseDown += l_MouseDown;
        l.MouseMove += l_MouseMove;
        l.MouseUp += l_MouseUp;
    }
}


// the currently moved Label:
Label mvLabel = null;

void l_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // keep reference
    mvLabel = (Label)sender;
}

void l_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // if we are dragging a label:
    if (mvLabel != null)
    {
        // mouse pos in window coords
        Point  mvPoint = this.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
        // the label is still in the FLP, so we start the drg action:
        if (mvLabel.Parent != this)
        {
            mvLabel.Parent = this;
            mvLabel.Location = mvPoint;
            mvLabel.BringToFront();
        }
        else
        {   
            // we are already in the form, so we just move
            mvLabel.Location = mvPoint;
        }
    }
}

void l_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // are we over a FLP? and if so which?
    Point MP = Control.MousePosition;
    FlowLayoutPanel FLP = null;

    Point mLoc1 = FLP1.PointToClient(MP);
    Point mLoc2 = FLP2.PointToClient(MP);

    if (FLP1.ClientRectangle.Contains(mLoc1)) FLP = FLP1;
    else if (FLP2.ClientRectangle.Contains(mLoc2)) FLP = FLP2;
    else return;  // no! nothing we can do..

    // yes, now find out if we are over a label..
    // ..or over an empty area
    mvLabel.SendToBack();
    Control cc = FLP.GetChildAtPoint(FLP.PointToClient(MP));
    // if we are over the FLP we can insert at the beginning or the end:
    // int mvIndex = 0; // to the beginning
    int mvIndex = FLP.Controls.Count; // to the end
    // we are over a Label, so we insert before it:
    if (cc != null) mvIndex = FLP.Controls.IndexOf(cc);

    // move the Label into the FLP
    FLP.Controls.Add(mvLabel);
    // move it to the right position:
    FLP.Controls.SetChildIndex(mvLabel, mvIndex);
    // let go of the reference
    mvLabel = null;

}
```

This lets you drag and drop `Lables` to and fro between two `FLPs` and also within the `FLPs` by dropping **onto** `Labels`.

Note that you will need a few extra lines if you want to allow dropping **between** `Labels` and still position there..